# Firestore Document Maps to List of Objects Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Firestore Document:

[image: Firestore]

Every field in the document is a Map. I would like to obtain these fields as a `List<Schedule>` in Kotlin but I couldn't get it.

I have this:

```kotlin
data class Schedule (
    val opo: String? = null,
    val startTime: Long? = null,
    val duration: Int? = null,
    val maxCapacity: Int? = null,
    val users: Map<String,String>? = null,
    val coachName: String? = null,
    val coachImage: String? = null
) {
    val attendees: Int = userList?.size ?: 0
}

data class DailySchedules (
    val list: List<Schedule>? = null
)
```

Each field should be a Schedule Object and I want to get all the fields as a List.

How can I do that?

I tried this in my repo:

```kotlin
override fun getDailySchedules(date: String) = callbackFlow {
    val schedulesDoc = schedulesRef.document(date)

    val snapshotListener = schedulesDoc.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        val dbResponse = if (snapshot != null) {

            val schedules = snapshot.toObject(DailySchedules::class.java)
            Log.d("PROVES", schedules.toString())

            Success(schedules)
        } else {
            Failure(e)
        }
        trySend(dbResponse)

    }
    awaitClose {
        snapshotListener.remove() }
}
```

I get this in the Log: DailySchedules(list=null)

Comment: Btw, nice question.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a listener to a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object, the `snapshot` object that you get from the lambda is an object of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot). When you call `.toObject(DailySchedules::class.java)` on such an object, it means that you're trying to map the `DocumentReference` object into an object of type `DailySchedules`, which is not possible. A `DailySchedules` object contains inside a `list` of type `List<Schedule>?`, while the `DocumentSnapshot` contains fields of type [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) (object).

To solve this, you can keep your actual document structure and try to read the data using [DocumentSnapshot#getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) and right after that dig inside the `Map<String!, Any!>?` object and create the list yourself. Or you can change the document structure a bit, by adding all those `Schedule` objects inside an array and then convert the document into an object of type `DailySchedules`. For that, I recommend checking the solution in the following resource:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: I was thinking about it. If I add all those Schedule objects inside an array, how can I change only one of this Schedule?

Comment: You have to read the document, find the element that you want to change in the array, then perform the change and write the document back to Firestore.

Comment: But this approach is not very efficient. Is it? What do you recommend?

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So if one approach solves the problem, then you should go a head with it.

Comment: I think I'll go for the first approach. Can you give me an example how to convert Map<Strinng!, Any!> to a Schedule?

Comment: Asking a follow-up question is typically a new post. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Okey Alex, thank you so much! It's all, appreciated.